# Meteor: access this

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

Multiple times in a row I've had the same problem with Meteor:

I am in a function (e.g. Hook) and cant access 'this':

```
AutoForm.addHooks('aaForm', {
    before: {
        insert: function (insertDoc, updateDoc, currentDoc) {
            // 'this' is overwritten here
        }
    }
});
```

Or even harder:
I use '[peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal/blob/master/main.js)'

I am currently on the route '/aa/**ID_HASH**' with

```
data = {
    name: "hello",
    _id: __ID_HASH__
}
```

and at some point I call
    Modal.show("modal", {"modalTemplate": template});

where 'modal' is

```
<template name="modal">
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                {{> Template.dynamic template=modalTemplate}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and 'template' is the name of the template I want to render it in.
In my case I render a quick form and want to access the original data object {name,_id} in the 'before' hook

So my question is how do I access/pass parameters to functions that overwrite 'this'?

Comment: by doing

`Modal.show("modal", {"modalTemplate": template, "data": this});`

(note the __"data":this__) I can access `this.data` in 

`Template.renderedModal.rendered = function(){
    context = this.data
};`

Is this the right way to pass data into functions that overwrite 'this'?

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be?

Comment: Best thing would be the data object, as I want to access it.

Comment: Ah, you want the template data? Have you tried `Template.instance()`?

Comment: **Template.currentData()** seems to return the right thing, thank you!